# Setting screenName in code

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm using Google Analytics for Android and I create my tracker like this:

```
    GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
    tracker = analytics.newTracker(context.getString(R.string.ga_tracking_id));
    tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
```

I have different trackingIds for different configurations so I can't inflate the tracker from the xml (since I can't refer to a string resource from xml).

I have enabled auto activity tracking in code, but I can't find any API to customize screen names which will appear in my reports. Instead I see full activity names in my reports.

There is [Tracker.setScreenName](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker.html#setScreenName(java.lang.String)) method but it seems to imply manual activity tracking.

How do I mimic screen configuration from tracker xml file in code? It usually looks like this:

```
<!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
<screenName name="com.mycompany.MyActivity">MyActivity Screen Name</screenName>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics v4 API doesn't provide a way to set the screen names in code when using automatic activity tracking. You need to disable automatic activity tracking `tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(false)` and call `GoogleAnalytics.reportActivityStart(activity)` from `onActivityStarted()` and `GoogleAnalytics.reportActivityStop(activity)` from `onActivityStop()` callbacks.

Here is a link to the application activity lifecycle callbacks:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html

Your code will look something like this:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private final String TRACKER_ID = "UA-12345678-1";

    private static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
    private static Tracker tracker;

    public static GoogleAnalytics analytics() {
        return analytics;
    }

    public static Tracker tracker() {
        return tracker;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        // analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
        tracker = analytics.newTracker(TRACKER_ID);

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
                tracker().setScreenName("My Activity");
                tracker().send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
                analytics().reportActivityStart(activity);
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {}

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {}

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
                analytics().reportActivityStop(activity);
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {}

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {}
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's smart. I have a question: is it necessary to call `analytics.reportActivityStart` and `analytics.reportActivityStop` since we send the screen hit using `tracker.send` anyway? The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html#reportActivityStart(android.app.Activity)) suggest that this method is valuable only when a tracker has auto-activity reporting turned on, but we have just turned it off, right?